# Writing a custom sum function for a list of numbers

Tags: python

I have a list and I want to calculate its average. After getting the average  I want to substract each item from the list with average value. After getting the all values I want to square and total the sum.

```
x=[17,13,12,15,16,14,16,16,18,19]
Average is 15.6
For example list look like: x=[17,13,12,15,16,14,16,16,18,19]
```

Step 1:

```
Find average value
sum(x)/len(x) 
average value is 15.6
```

Step 2:
subtract each item from the list with Average value

```
17-15.6  =  1.4
13-15.6  = -2.6
12-15.6  = -3.6
15-15.6  = -0.6
16-15.6  =  0.4
14-15.6  = -1.6
16-15.6  =  0.4
16-15.6  =  0.4
18-15.6  =  2.4
19-15.6  =  3.4
```

Step 3: 
After that I want to apply the square of each result

```
1.4   * 1.4    = 1.96
-2.6  * -2.6   = 6.76
-3.6  * -3.6   = 12.96
-0.6  * -0.6   = 0.36
0.4   * 0.4    = 0.16
-1.6  * -1.6   = 2.56
0.4   * 0.4    = 0.16
0.4   * 0.4    = 0.16
2.4   * 2.4    = 5.76
3.4   * 3.4    = 11.56
```

Step 4: 
After that i want to sum the squares

```
1.96 + 6.76 + 12.96 0.36 +0.16 + 2.56 + 0.16 + 0.16 + 5.76 + 11.56 = 42.4
```

I tried this approach I am able to get up to step 3

```
def sumx(x):
    for i in x:                        #
        result=i-sum(x)/len(x)         #
        result=result*result           #
        #result="{:.2f}".format(result)
        print("{:.2f}".format(result))
        total=0
        for i in result:
            total +=i
    return (total)
sumx(x)
```

**Error Message**

> Error message for i in result: TypeError: 'float' object is not
>   iterable

The desired output is 42.4

Comment: Please add your code and the error message you receive after step 3.

Comment: `new_list = [item * item for item in old_list]`? Without the code it's hard to say. Also, your profile pic suggests you're coming from R; you'll be disappointed with Python unless you start doing this stuff with the NumPy library

Comment: **Error message**
for i in result:
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable

Comment: Nowhere in your post does `for i in result` exist. It is _impossible_ to debug code that we can't even see. Please [edit] your post to show your code.

Comment: Don't compute the sum in each loop! Also, your `for i in result` is nonsense, `result` is a number.

Comment: Are you able to use numpy? You have some Python answers already but the numpy answer is not the correct approach with the library

Comment: I added my code could you please check it

Comment: Along with the comment above, note that this code will throw a syntax error as the first `for` is not indented correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is in here:

```
total=0
for i in result:
    total +=i
```

Here result is just a number and not a list. Therefore this entire code is written wrong.

Instead you can initialize total at the starting position of function and get rid of the for loop.

Here is a simple code:

```
x = [17,13,12,15,16,14,16,16,18,19]

average = sum (x) / float (len (x))
total = 0

for number in x:
    result = pow ((number - average), 2)
    total += result
print total
```

If you want it as a function:

```
x = [17,13,12,15,16,14,16,16,18,19]

def sumx(x):
    average = sum (x) / float (len (x))
    total = 0
    for i in x:                        
        result = i - average
        result = result * result           
        total += result
    return (total)

print sumx(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you want to compute a mean and variance of the list `x`.

```
x = [17, 13, 12, 15, 16, 14, 16, 16, 18, 19]
n = len(x)
mean = sum(x) / n
var = sum((t - mean)**2 for t in x) / n
```

Remove the division by `n` in the computation of `var` if you only want the sum of squares.

So that, if you only want to return the sum of squares:

```
def ssq(x):
    mean = sum(x) / len(x)
    return sum((t - mean)**2 for t in x)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `numpy` and list comprehension:

```
import numpy as np
x=[17,13,12,15,16,14,16,16,18,19]

# using mean function from numpy
sum((y - np.mean(x))**2 for y in x) # 42.4

# calculating mean on our own (pure python)
sum((y - (sum(x)/float(len(x))))**2 for y in x) # 42.4

# function to calculate sse
def sse(x):
    m = np.mean(x)
    return sum((y - m)**2 for y in x)
```

Comment: ... this isn't using numpy at all. Why would you run a list comprehension when you have numpy?

Comment: I meant,it saves doing `sum(x)/len(x)` and simply use `np.mean`

Comment: Yeah but what you have now is a half-cooked numpy approach :P

Comment: isn't it `import numpy as np` @YOLO

Comment: And note, `numpy` doesn't work on lists. Behind the scenes it's copying that data to a new array, so it could well end up being slower than python.

Comment: Not only is it silly to use numpy here in a sum, in both solutions (with and without numpy) you recompute the mean in each loop.

Comment: Thanks it's working me 
I need  to write def function could you help me

Comment: @thrinadhn added it, take a look.

Answer (score 0):

My attempt to your question even though it is not so elaborate as the other answers as I have figured out but it is basically step-by-step :D

```
import numpy as np

def std(x = [], to = None):

    if to is None:
        to = []
        to.append(x)

    y = np.mean(to)

    z = []
    for item in to:
        z.append((item - y)**2)

    print(sum(z[0]))

std([17,13,12,15,16,14,16,16,18,19])
```

Comment: @alex-p, never use mutable default arguments - https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/#mutable-default-arguments

Comment: @alex-p. my remark was general. In this case you don't need default value. i.e. it doesn't make sense to have it. Also this line print(sum(z[0])) doesn't make sense - z[0] is just the first element of z list. So in fact you apply sum() on a single element of z list.

Comment: @buran, after I added the second parameter to the function, the variable `z` created an array of the list. When I would not select the first element, I would not get the sum of the list but instead the full list printed.

Comment: that is because you append `x` to `to`, yet you still have mutable default argument

Answer (score 0):

You can use `numpy` and vectorise the computation:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([17,13,12,15,16,14,16,16,18,19])
normalized_vector = x - np.mean(x)
result = np.dot(normalized_vector, normalized_vector)
```

...since the dot product is equal to the sum of squared elements. To be even more concise:

```
result = np.var(x) * x.size
```

...which calculates *n* times *variance* which should be equal to what you want.